# Есть ли в C# возможность получить массив свойства без перебора листа?

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть у меня вот такой Листик типа **headInfo**.

```
    public enum typeHead { date, str, integer }

    public struct headInfo
    {
        public string name;
        public typeHead type;
    }

    public static List<headInfo> headsSQL = new List<headInfo>()
    {
        { new headInfo { name = "date_import", type = typeHead.date } },
        { new headInfo { name = "num_rz", type = typeHead.integer } },
        { new headInfo { name = "date_rz", type = typeHead.date } },
        { new headInfo { name = "str", type = typeHead.str } }
    };
```

Можно ли из него получить массив name-ов не перебирая этот Листик циклом?

Comment: Можно: `var names = headsSQL.Select(p => p.name).ToArray();` Но под капотом все равно будет перебор в цикле

Comment: У вас на столе стопка анкет пользователей, вам из них надо получить все имена, ваши действия? Наверно будете брать каждую анкету, искать строку с именем и записывать куда надо, верно? Другие решения данной задачи есть?

Comment: а может есть другой способ объявления данных? Чтобы можно было обратиться как к определенной строке, так и к столбцу без перебора?
Кажется DataTable называется, может еще что есть?

Comment: Какую задачу вы решаете для начала нам поведайте, почему вам так "противен" перебор? Если используется например база данных, то там есть так называемая "ленивая" загрузка и при помощи `LINQ` получается вся нужная информация (но там как вам и сказали выше тот же перебор).

Answer (score 1):

```cs
readonly Dictionary<string, HeadInfo> heads;

public static ICollection<string> Names => heads.Keys;

public static void AddInfo(HeadInfo info)
{
    // checking...

    heads.Add(info.Name, info);
}
```

`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.KeyCollection` - виртуальная, т. е. ссылается на др. коллекцию (в нашем случае на словарь) ([ссылка](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Generic/Dictionary.cs)), и ссылка на её находится внутри словаря, зн. можно просто использовать функцию для её возврата, обёрнутую в св-во.